# Is it possible to center specific two widgets within a Stack in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The widget to be placed currently is as shown in the figure below.
I have a TextA widget with an unknown width.
The TextB widget overlaps the TextA widget and must be centered on each other.

I've heard that in Flutter, the parent Container determines the location of its children.
So, after the size of the TextA widget is decided, is there a way to center the TextB widget with the TextA widget?

[Align TextB to center position of TextA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAj3u.png)

Comment: see `CompositedTransformTarget` / `CompositedTransformFollower`

Comment: thank you for the reply.
When I checked CompositedTransformTarget and CompositedTransformFollower, it seems to be using Overlay.
Is it difficult to align using only a layout like Stack without Overlay?

Comment: you dont need `Overlay` - `Stack` is good enough

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.